# Not getting subsets as expected

Tags: java, algorithm, data-mining, subset, apriori

I am trying to find the count of frequent Items in the dataset.
So initialy I tried to find the subset of the input string

```
Input:
coke,cracker,beer
coke,cracker
```

What I did so far is

```
String[] transaction = value.toString().split(delim);
/*
 * Get subsets
 */
System.out.println("Transaction----"+Arrays.toString(transaction));
Arrays.sort(transaction);
int len = transaction.length;
long numofSubsets = (long) Math.pow(2, transaction.length);

for (long i = 1; i < numofSubsets; i++) {

    String j = String.format("%" + len + "s", Long.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0');
    String addVal = "";
    for (int l = 0; l < j.length(); l++) {
            if (j.charAt(l) == '0') {
             //do nothing
             } 
             else{
            addVal += transaction[l]+delim;
             System.out.println("addval---------- "+addVal);
             addVal = addVal.substring(0, addVal.length()-1);
              }
    }
}
```

And output is

```
Transaction----[coke, cracker, beer]
addval---------- cracker
addval---------- coke
addval---------- coke
addval---------- coke,cracker
addval---------- beer
addval---------- beer
addval---------- beer,cracker
addval---------- beer
addval---------- beer,coke
addval---------- beer
addval---------- beer,coke
addval---------- beer,coke,cracker
Transaction----[coke, cracker]
addval---------- cracker
addval---------- coke
addval---------- coke
addval---------- coke,cracker
```

I expect the subset as

```
 coke
    cracker
    beer
    coke,cracker
    coke,beer
    cracker,beer
    coke
    cracker
    coke,cracker


Transaction----[coke, cracker]
    addval---------- cracker
    addval---------- coke
    addval---------- coke
    addval---------- coke,cracker
```

Here `coke` is getting `repeated`.

Am I doing anything wrong.

Please Advice.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you are trying to implement `APRIORI`, you need to study that algorithm much more carefully. It never enumerates all subsets of a transaction - this will kill you on any non-trivial data set. Also your code quality has much room for improvement. Get rid of all `String`s. Google for `supermarket.arff` and check if you can process this data set, it is okay for unit testing.

Comment: I am implementing apriori in hadoop mapreduce.So I think the best way is to pass the subset and count the occurence.Then we will get the frequent itemsets.I am able to get the output.Any other optimized way?

Comment: It's certainly not APRIORI the way you're doing it. It's a naive frequent itemset mining instead, because you left out all the clever ideas from APRIORI. Estimate the amount of data you need to transmit over the network, to see how badly your approach scales. Probably a good APRIORI solution on a single host scales better than your Hadoop version...

Comment: Any way to optimize the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the placement of your `println` statement. Since it's inside the loop which is generating the string to print, it prints every prefix of the string before printing the string you want. e.g. when you want "coke, crackers, beer" you get

`coke
 coke, crackers
 coke, crackers, beer`

To fix this, just move your `println` outside of the loop.